# htacces, Redirect on deny

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

i'd like to make a redirect after a deny - because now, it's shows the apache Startpage.

My htaccess-code:

```
 ErrorDocument 403 /forbidden.php
 Deny from .ru
 Deny from .cn
```

unfortunately it doesn't work, why?

thanks 
thomas

Comment: It should be showing your `/forbidden.php`

Answer (score 0):

This is only working if Apache can geht the DN of the client by double reverse lookup. If the reverse lookup has no result your rule will not work and the client gets access. You see, that this is not very reliable and you should switch to GEOIP.

If the deny rule is working and the desired page does not show, remember that the location is relative to the document root. So if your `forbidden.php` in subfolder `/test` you will need to set the rule like this:

```
ErrorDocument 403 /test/forbidden.php
Deny from .ru
Deny from .cn
```

Even if `.htaccess` and `forbidden.php` are in `/test` subfolder.

Comment: the deny works fine, but the redirect to forbidden.php is not working. any ideas?

Comment: If you remove `ErrorDocument 403 /forbidden.php` you will get the default 403 page? Please remember to test this in private browsing tab in FF or Chrome because of browser caching. Also if you set `ErrorDocument 403 /forbidden.php` to `ErrorDocument 403 Not for you!` it will show "Not for you!"?